# Mysql doesn't return the right hour?

Tags: php

I have these 'created' and 'modified' fields in several of my tables, but I've just realized that the hour that appears in those tables isn't the right one, but an hour later, so let's say it is 10:47:05 in local time then the hour that is stored to the database is 11 instead of 10, and it's always the same, I never get the right hour.

**EDIT:** Ok guys I tried to set time zone from the MySQL configuration file (**my.ini**), adding **default-time-zone = '-05:00'** at [myqld] section and after that I checked the global and session timezone to see if everything was alright,and apparently it was, but when I insert or update  some records and check the 'created' and 'modified' field to see if now the hour is the right one, much to my disappointed they still are an hour later than the current time.

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a timezone issue. What is your server time zone, what is mySQL's time zone?

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?? It's a DB configuration problem.

Comment: kill the cakephp tag - it isn't a cakephp question in the least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've finally worked it out and it turned out that it wasn't mysql, it wasn't even CakePhp - it was PHP!!!!.

[Here's](http://www.rasyid.net/2007/08/29/datetimezone-in-phpini-for-php5/) what I did to solve this problem:

Comment: You see. I knew you could do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This definately looks to be a timezone issue. If you don't have access to setting the timezone, you can always pass mysql the unix timestamp from your code to set the value to the field. For example if your field is DATETIME, using PHP you could write "INSERT table SET datetime=FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(".time().")";, if it's just a timestamp field you can just pass time() as a value. The other alternative for DATETIME is to send a MYSQL formatted date string using php's date function.

It's best to set the timezone of your servers but if you can't, the above should suffice

EDIT: The code above is purely an example, so it prob won't work in a copy and paste situation, it's purely a guide